# Give double value to Geopoint in GoogleMap overlays

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to point to a Google map location using overlay. For this purpose  latitude and longitude values will be assigned to a GeoPoint, but it only accepts int values.

How can I assign it a double value? Or is there another solution to point to an exact location?

```
point = new GeoPoint((int)t.getLati(),(int)t.getLongi())
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Since [GeoPoint](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/GeoPoint.html) accepts latitudes and longitudes in microdegrees, simply create your point like so:

```
GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint((int)(latitude * 1e6),
                              (int)(longitude * 1e6));
```

Comment: @Roman Nurik, I have done the same thing but there is slight variation in the points. I am getting lat/lng from google maps api and converting it to GeoPoints and drawing path. But when i compare it with google maps path, the path which i draw in my app is slighly different. Can you please help me if you have any idea.