# How to get E6 format of Longitude Latitude for Google Maps on Android

Tags: android, google-maps, latitude-longitude

how do i find out the **SPECIFIC** E6 values of longitude latitude of a location.
For example, i googled for long-lat of Asuncion, the capital city of Paraguay. It returns me:

`The latitude and longitude of Asuncion, Paraguay is 25°16' S, 57°40 W`

Now how do i convert THIS format of long-lat into E6 format of long-lat which android understands? What exactly IS THIS **E6** thing?

[p.s. i also googled for E6 long-lat of Asuncion....... with no luck]

Answer (score 26, accepted):

## So it's a two step process - [thanks to **hooked82**'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7049966/how-to-get-e6-format-of-longitude-latitude-for-google-maps-on-android/7145860#7145860)

---

**step 1. Conversion from DMS to Decimal Degrees** [From Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_coordinate_conversion#Conversion_from_DMS_to_Decimal_Degree)

> Given a DMS (Degrees, Minutes, Seconds) coordinate such as **87°43′41″ W**, it's trivial to convert it to a number of decimal degrees using the following methods:
>
> Total number of degrees
>   
>  **= 87**
>
> Total number of seconds
>   
>  **= 43′41″ = (43*60 + 41*1) = 2621 seconds.**
>
> The fractional part is total number of seconds divided by 3600
>   
>  **= 2621 / 3600 = 0.728056**
>
> Add fractional degrees to the whole degrees to produce the final result
>   
>  **= 87 + 0.728056 = 87.728056.**
>
> Since it is a West longitude coordinate, negate the result.
>   
>  **= -87.728056.**

Long-Lat reference:

```
Lat.  North = +
Lat.  South = -
Long. East  = +
Long. West  = -
```

---

**step 2. Conversion from Decimal Degrees to MicroDegrees (the E6 format)** [From SO discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577866/android-geopoint-with-lat-long-values/3577919#3577919)

> **MicroDegrees** (the E6 format) = **DecimalDegrees** * **1e6**
>   
>  --- [as mentioned in AndroidDevGuide as well](http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html)

thus,

```
float lat   = -23.4456f;   //in DecimalDegrees
float lng   = 45.44334f;   //in DecimalDegrees
GeoPoint gp = new GeoPoint((int)(lat * 1E6), (int)(lng * 1E6));
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure of a programmatic approach to converting a DMS Coordinate to Microdegrees, but there is a manual conversion process which I came across at:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_coordinate_conversion#Conversion_from_DMS_to_Decimal_Degree

Also, take a look at this SO question:

[Android GeoPoint with lat/long values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577866/android-geopoint-with-lat-long-values/3577919#3577919)

If you're manually trying to get GPS coordinates and want values that Android can handle, you can always go to Google Maps and Right-Click on a point on the map and select "What's Here".  It will give you the lat/long of that position, though there are many ways of getting these.