# GeoPoint not working when passed a variable

Tags: android, android-mapview

I am and Android/Java newbie and am having trouble creating a GeoPoint when I try to send it a variable, but it woks fine when I send it a literal value.

In the below code block, The toast message displays the correct latitude (retrieved from the strings.xml

How can I set the Latitude using a variable?

```
Integer intLat = Integer.valueOf(R.string.MexCityLat);
Toast.makeText(HelloGoogleMapsActivity.this, intLat, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(intLat , -99120000);  //this puts my point near North Pole
//GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(19240000, -99120000);  //this puts my point in Mexico City

OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(point, "Hola, Mundo!", "I'm in Mexico City!");
```

Comment: have you checked what is the value of intLat is correct value you are getting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**GeoPoint**

```
public GeoPoint(int latitudeE6,int longitudeE6)
```

Constructs a GeoPoint with the given latitude and longitude, measured in microdegrees (degrees * 1E6).

**Parameters:**

```
 latitudeE6 - The point's latitude. This will be clamped to between -80 degrees and +80 degrees inclusive, in order to maintain accuracy in the Mercator projection.
 longitudeE6 - The point's longitude. This will be normalized to be greater than -180 degrees and less than or equal to +180 degrees.
```

Also refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577866/android-geopoint-with-lat-long-values) for how to convert double,float to geopoint. and be sure you are getting right value for intLat

Comment: Thank you. My real problem was that I was not getting the correct value for intLat. I changed:

Comment: The problem was that intLat had the wrong value. I was not reading from the resource file correctly. I think it is working for me now.