# Getting wrong gps location using locationMangager android

Tags: android, gps, location, locationmanager

i am making just a little Android app using mapView and the LocationManager. 
My LocationManager should listen to the location and notify if my location changes over a user's defined tolerance.
If my LocationManager notice a Location changing it should send a sms.

```
lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000L, Float.parseFloat(txtToleranz.getText().toString()), this);
```

Here I am not sure if the method requestLocationUpdates takes always the current value of the textfield or only the given start value...?

Also my application should show my position in the mapView, but the position is totally wrong...why? I am running my app on a real device.

```
                double lat = location.getLatitude();
            double lng = location.getLongitude();

            String currentLocation = " Lat: " + lat + " Lng: " + lng + " Tol: " + Toleranz;
            point = new GeoPoint((int) lat * 1000000, (int) lng * 1000000);
            mapController.animateTo(point);
            mapController.setZoom(15);
            System.out.println(currentLocation);
```

Thank you for any help!
Best regards Daniel

Answer (score 0):

According to [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577866/android-geopoint-with-lat-long-values) the `GeoPoint` may be getting constructed incorrectly, this could cause an incorrect location. As for the `LocationManager`, the `requestLocationUpdates` method is only getting run once, meaning it's taking the `EditText's` value when the the method was run, it will not update unless you tell it to. There might be a method inside the the `LocationManager` class to do that.

**EDIT**

Ignore the part about the GeoPoint, upon further reading you are correct in multiplying your long/lat by 1000000

Comment: Do you have an idea how to work with the GeoPoint better or something like this?

Comment: Why don't you pass the lat/long to the users map application and get that to display it? I've used summit like `Intent maps = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
     Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q="+latitude+","+longitude+" (Your location)"));
     maps.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps", "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
     startActivity(maps);` before. It works well.

Comment: Where shall i implement this? Which method?

Comment: When you long/lat has been assigned.