# same coordinates different places in android and google maps

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview

I am taking the location using location manager in android like this:

```
LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
Location lastKnownLoc = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

geoPoint= new GeoPoint((int) (lastKnownLoc.getLatitude()*1000000),(int) (lastKnownLoc.getLongitude())*1000000);
```

And setting the map view to this coordinate:

```
myMC = myMapView.getController();
myMC.setCenter(geoPoint);
```

But the place that i got is the actual place where the location is. When i give the coordinates to google maps on https://maps.google.com/ i got the actual place. Why this occurs like this? Can anyone help me please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the last known location. Not the current location.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/obtaining-user-location.html#Updates

Thats shows you how to get the current location and gives some sample code.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577866/android-geopoint-with-lat-long-values) question would suggest the geopoint is not calculated correctly

Comment: I know i am getting the last knowm location. My problem is not this. My problem is getting different places with same coordinates.

Comment: yeap this is the answer of my question. Thank you!