# Getting wrong location in LocationManager

Tags: android, maps, locationmanager

I get totally wrong location when using the LocationManager with the Network provider. I get a Location out in the sea outside Africa, the accuracy is around 2000. My Google Maps is showing the accurate position.

Does anyone have a idea about what the problem can be? It is the same when I use the `getLastKnownLocation()`.

Comment: Have you checked the actual location, sea off Africa sounds like 0,0 to me.

Comment: That was the problem! I added to small values to my GeoPoint. Found eventually the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2227816/how-to-give-double-value-to-geopoint-in-googlemap-overlays 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The network location provider is extremely inaccurate. Usually if you are connected to WiFi, you can get within 100 meters, but on cell towers, 2000 meters is pretty normal. There's not really a problem, persay.

If Google Maps is able to get an accurate location with GPS turned off, then it is likely due to some very advanced location management that they do. But 2000 meters with Network Location, unfortunately, is normal in all of my test cases.

**EDIT:**

> It is to say that the value of location.getAccuracy() is around 2000 (not a value in meters).

When getAccuracy() returns a value of 2000, it means meters. Here's what [The Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#getAccuracy()) say about `getAccuracy()`:

> Returns the accuracy of the fix in meters. If hasAccuracy() is false, 0.0 is returned.

But it returns a `float` value, and while it doesn't display the unit, it is still meters.

Comment: Oh, sorry. It is to say that the value of location.getAccuracy() is around 2000 (not a value in meters). The accuracy in position is about half the world. I am in Sweden and it says I am in Africa, kind of big  ;)

Comment: @TobiasEkblom I updated my answer with further explanation. Does that explain?

Comment: Yes, now I understand the accuracy. My problem was that I used the wrong values to my GeoPint. But i set your answer as a correct one though I cant do it on the comment on my question.