# Overlay behavior when zooming

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview, overlays

I am having trouble with overlays. I have drawn a polygon overlay on the map, however, when I zoom in or out, the edges no longer align with where I want them to. How can I fix this?

Here is what it looks like when I start the app (it covers the whole parking lot perfectly):
[Correct](http://i1278.photobucket.com/albums/y510/kvothe89/Correct_zps7021c983.jpg)

Here is what it looks like when I zoom out (edges no longer line up with parking lot. The overlay looks a bit bigger than the parking lot):
[Zoomed out](http://i1278.photobucket.com/albums/y510/kvothe89/Zoom_Out_zps735faf91.jpg)

Also, it doesn't align well when I zoom in. In this case the overlay is a bit smaller that the parking lot. (Sorry, stackoverflow won't let me post more that 2 links)

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Here is the code:

```
private Projection projection; 
private List<Overlay> mapOverlays;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView); 
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

    MapController mc = mapView.getController();
    mc.setZoom(17); 
    mc.animateTo(new GeoPoint((int)(32.734248*1E6), (int)(-97.113448*1E6)));

    mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();        
    projection = mapView.getProjection();
    mapOverlays.add(new MyOverlay());        

    mapView.postInvalidate();
}

@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    return false;
}

class MyOverlay extends Overlay{

    public MyOverlay(){

    }   

    public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapv, boolean shadow){
        super.draw(canvas, mapv, shadow);

        Paint   mPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        mPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        mPaint.setAlpha(100);

        GeoPoint gP1 = new GeoPoint(32733839,-97112976);
        GeoPoint gP2 = new GeoPoint(32733875, -97113448);
        GeoPoint gP3 = new GeoPoint(32734961,-97113455);
        GeoPoint gP4 = new GeoPoint(32734953, -97112962);

        Point p1 = new Point();
        Point p2 = new Point();
        Point p3 = new Point();
        Point p4 = new Point();
        Path path = new Path();

        projection.toPixels(gP1, p1);
        projection.toPixels(gP2, p2);
        projection.toPixels(gP3, p3);
        projection.toPixels(gP4, p4);

        path.moveTo(p1.x, p1.y);
        path.lineTo(p2.x,p2.y);
        path.lineTo(p3.x,p3.y);
        path.lineTo(p4.x,p4.y);

        canvas.drawPath(path, mPaint);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You should post some code because you just might have precision problems.

Comment: Are you sure you converted your points [correctly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2227816/how-to-give-double-value-to-geopoint-in-googlemap-overlays)?

Comment: Yes, they're in microdegrees.

Comment: All looks correct (sorry-I missed the microdegrees)... Last item I would verify see if explicitly calling view.invalidate/postInvalidate (non-ui thread) at higher zoom helps...

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what non-ui thread means. I added mapv.invalidate(); after canvas.drawPath, in the draw method. Is this what you meant? This doesn't fix it.

Comment: invalidate: one is safe to call only from gui thread - invalidate(), non-ui thread  - postInvalidate(). That is what I meant. Too bad it does not help you.

Comment: I also tried changing the original zoom level, to get the application to start at a different zoom level. That does not work either. There is only one zoom level where the overlay aligns perfectly. On other zoom levels, it doesn't really align well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everytime the zoom changes, `Projection` also changes. Even when you make a large move in the map without changing zoom, projection may change.

To correct your code you need to add the line as bellow:

```
public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapv, boolean shadow){ 
    super.draw(canvas, mapv, shadow); 

    Projection projection = mapv.getProjection();  //Add this line

    Paint   mPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG); 
    mPaint.setColor(Color.RED); 
    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL); 
    mPaint.setAlpha(100); 

    GeoPoint gP1 = new GeoPoint(32733839,-97112976); 
    GeoPoint gP2 = new GeoPoint(32733875, -97113448); 
    GeoPoint gP3 = new GeoPoint(32734961,-97113455); 
    GeoPoint gP4 = new GeoPoint(32734953, -97112962); 

    Point p1 = new Point(); 
    Point p2 = new Point(); 
    Point p3 = new Point(); 
    Point p4 = new Point(); 
    Path path = new Path(); 

    projection.toPixels(gP1, p1); 
    projection.toPixels(gP2, p2); 
    projection.toPixels(gP3, p3); 
    projection.toPixels(gP4, p4); 

    path.moveTo(p1.x, p1.y); 
    path.lineTo(p2.x,p2.y); 
    path.lineTo(p3.x,p3.y); 
    path.lineTo(p4.x,p4.y); 

    canvas.drawPath(path, mPaint); 
}
```

And you can remove the projection created in `onCreate()`.

--EDITED--

**Improvements - Quick wins**

`onDraw()` is called twice eveytime you move the map or change zoom level, so it's important to make it as possible. Bellow you can find some suggestions:

```
private List<Overlay> mapOverlays; 

@Override 
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 

    MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);  
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true); 

    MapController mc = mapView.getController(); 
    mc.setZoom(17);  
    mc.animateTo(new GeoPoint((int)(32.734248*1E6), (int)(-97.113448*1E6))); 

    mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();         
    mapOverlays.add(new MyOverlay());         

    mapView.postInvalidate(); 
} 

@Override 
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() { 
    return false; 
} 

class MyOverlay extends Overlay{ 

    //Moved objects that need only one instance to the initialization, to avoid creating a new copy of each every time draw() runs  
    private Paint   mPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);

    private GeoPoint gP1 = new GeoPoint(32733839,-97112976); 
    private GeoPoint gP2 = new GeoPoint(32733875, -97113448); 
    private GeoPoint gP3 = new GeoPoint(32734961,-97113455); 
    private GeoPoint gP4 = new GeoPoint(32734953, -97112962); 

    private Point p1 = new Point(); 
    private Point p2 = new Point(); 
    private Point p3 = new Point(); 
    private Point p4 = new Point(); 
    private Path path = new Path(); 

    public MyOverlay(){
        //mPaint settings done on class creation, to avoid repeating them on draw() call 
        mPaint.setColor(Color.RED); 
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL); 
        mPaint.setAlpha(100); 
    }    

    public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapv, boolean shadow){ 
        super.draw(canvas, mapv, shadow); 

        //draw is always called twice, one with shadow equal to true and one to false.
        //This can be used to draw the same image with shadow
        //But you are not using shadows, so you can immediately return half of the calls, and reduce the draw() effort by half
        if(shadow) return;

        Projection projection = mapv.getProjection();

        projection.toPixels(gP1, p1); 
        projection.toPixels(gP2, p2); 
        projection.toPixels(gP3, p3); 
        projection.toPixels(gP4, p4); 

        path.rewind();
        path.moveTo(p1.x,p1.y); 
        path.lineTo(p2.x,p2.y); 
        path.lineTo(p3.x,p3.y); 
        path.lineTo(p4.x,p4.y); 

        canvas.drawPath(path, mPaint); 
    } 
}
```

**Improvements - a more complex one**

The improvement I'm describing bellow is a overkill for you current overlay. It only makes sense when you have realy huge paths to draw.

When you move the map, without zomming it, with the code above the path will be recreated and redrawn in a different place to be aligned with the map. But the path you are creating is the same size, same shape as the previous one, just in a different position.

You can achive the same result using:

```
path.offset(dx, dy);
```

where `dx, dy` is the number of pixels you need to move the path to keep it aligned with the map. Of course, you need to keep track where was the map last time you offset the path, so you can offset the path to the new map position.

If you have a path with several thousands of points, offseting the path will be about 100 times faster then redrawing it.

You also need to keep track on zoom level, as you still need to recreate the path when zoom changes. You can't use `getCurrentZoomLevel()` to do it, as it´s not synchronized with zoom animation. You need to test `longitudeSpan()` value changes, to be able to have a synchronized path creation with zoom change animation.

I hope this will help.

Regards.

Comment: So I added Projection projection = mapv.getProjection();. mapView is for the mapView in the onCreate(). This does not work for me.

Comment: Dear @Kvothe, when someone spend time helping me and point out an error in my code, I say something like "Thanks for your help, and I've corrected the error you point out", and then, if my code still not work as I expect, I would say "Although, my code still have additional errors because now have the following behaviour ... Can you please help me find them?". I will wait for a proper appreciation for finding one crude error, before spend any more time looking at your code, and I believe you will find out that not many people will spend time helping you, if you don't show appreciation.

Comment: Sorry I didn't mean for it to come out that way (I blame the lack of sleep). What I meant to say is that I have made the change you suggested, but it did not work. It did not change anything, and the app behaves in the same way. I really do appreciate the help you and others provide on this website, and I really did not mean to sound ungrateful. So, would you please accept my apology and take another look at it when you get a chance? Thank you.

Comment: You are welcome :-). I noticed that you are not closing the path, but that should not be the problem. I'll have a closer look, and I'll come back to you.

Comment: There several things that you could do to improve your code in terms of performance and memory utilization (if you want I can share it with yout), but there is nothing more that could be considered wrong. I've tested your code and compared it with the behaviour of google maps using Internet Explorer. If you open this link https://maps.google.pt/maps?q=32.734953,+-97.112962&hl=pt-PT&ll=32.734806,-97.112714&spn=0.001225,0.002642&sll=32.734702,-97.113073&sspn=0.001234,0.002642&t=m&z=19 (it's your parking) and change zoom, you will see that the marker will move slightly up and down. (continued)

Comment: It looks like the problem is with the accuracy of the map itself in different zoom levels. For this specific problem, I don't see any other solution beside adding/subtracting the error value to the point coordinate, depending on the zoom level.

Comment: Or, adjust it to look perfect a medium level, and then when you zoom in/out you will have only half of deviation. Not so perfect, but could be a reasonable solution.

Comment: If you want the improvements, let me know. The are a few quick wins, and some more complicated.

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes I would appreciate any and all improvements that are possible, as well as any other feedback. I will be away from my computer for a couple of hours, but I look forward to hearing what you have to say. Thanks once again.

Comment: Thank you very much. This really does help a lot. I had no idea about draw being called twice! I will look into the longitudeSpan() method and see if I can also get that working. Thank you.

Comment: As I said, it's a overkill for your current overlay, but it's a good practice for a large one. Let me know if you have trouble putting it to work. Regards.